# Broadcastreceiver cannot receive when activity not opened

Tags: java, android

I have a notepad activity that opens up a window dialog version of it where user can go to another app and still type on the notepad

For both notepad to have the same content, I used broadcastReceiver to set the text of the notepad activity to the one in the dialog when the user is done.

Activity's BroadcastReceiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final globalVariable globalVariable = (globalVariable) getApplicationContext();
        et_editor.setText(globalVariable.getScriptEditorText());
        Toast.makeText(Script_editor.this, "Script Editor have been updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Close Button of the Dialog:

```
btn_Close = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_Close);
btn_Close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setTitle("Would you like to update the editor?")
                .setNegativeButton("No, discard the changes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(ColorCoordinatePickerService.this, "Changes have been discarded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        stopSelf();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Yes, update with changes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        final globalVariable globalVariable = (globalVariable) getApplicationContext();
                        globalVariable.setScriptEditortext(CCEditor.getText().toString());
                        Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
                        sendBroadcast(intent);

                        dialog.dismiss();
                        stopSelf();
                    }
                })
                .create();

        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```

It works BUT the user have to go back to the notepad activity (cannot be in another app or activity).

How do I update the notepad's content without having to "open" it up?

Comment: Are you unregistering receiver in onPause() of the activity? If yes then it won't receive call to onReceive() function. Register and unregister receiver in onCreate and onDestroy respectively for this particular case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queue the changes in `BroadcastReceiver` and when `NotepadActivity` resumes set the changes in the `EditText`. The queue doesn't need to be an actual queue, you can persist the last broadcast receiver data somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it may be clear your global variable on moving from activity to another activity, also you are declaring the instance of global variable so it will set value in instance not in main variable and therefor you will not get it on receiver.

So I think you should set value in intent and then get it on receiver and manage it so it will work.

Check below, first your click event of dialog box method

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           final globalVariable globalVariable = (globalVariable) getApplicationContext();
           globalVariable.setScriptEditortext(CCEditor.getText().toString());
           Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);

           intent.putExtra("global_variable","" + CCEditor.getText().toString());
           sendBroadcast(intent);

           dialog.dismiss();
           stopSelf();
   }
```

And now get value in receiver as like below.

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       final globalVariable globalVariable = (globalVariable) getApplicationContext();

       String strData = intent.getExtras().getString("global_variable");

       et_editor.setText(strData);
       Toast.makeText(Script_editor.this, "Script Editor have been updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

without opening acitivity,you want to update data then only one way you can do it.when you receive in receiver set all data into sharepreference.Whenever your notepad activity opens you can set take data from sharepreference and set it into notepad activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).

Example: [How to use it](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)